# How to combine (merge) two datatable Frame in python

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation, py-datatable

Given two [datatable Frame](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame.html). How to combine (merge) them in one frame?

dt_f_A =

```
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| A_at_1 | A_at_2 | A_at_3 | ... | A_at_m |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| v_1    |        |        |     |        |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| ...    |        |        |     |        |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| v_N    |        |        |     |        |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
```

dt_f_B =

```
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| B_at_1 | B_at_2 | B_at_3 | ... | B_at_k |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| w_1    |        |        |     |        |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| ...    |        |        |     |        |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| w_N    |        |        |     |        |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
```

The expected result (dt_f_A concat(combine or merge) dt_f_B)

```
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| A_at_1 | A_at_2 | A_at_3 | ... | A_at_m | B_at_1 | B_at_2 | B_at_3 | ... | B_at_k |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| v_1    |        |        |     |        | w_1    |        |        |     |        |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| ...    |        |        |     |        | ...    |        |        |     |        |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| v_N    |        |        |     |        | w_N    |        |        |     |        |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
```

We consider three cases:

**Case 1:** **a)** The two frames have exactly **the same numbers of rows**, and **b)** **unique attributes** in the columns.

**Case 2:** The number of rows is different

**Case 3:** the attributes are not unique (there is a duplication)

@sammywemmy Thank you for the valuable comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:** **a)** The two frames have exactly **the same numbers of rows**, and **b)** **unique attributes** in the columns

1- use [cbind](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame/cbind.html#datatable.Frame.cbind) :  `dt_f_A.cbind(dt_f_B)`
**or**
2- use :  `dt_f_A[:,dt_f_B.names] = dt_f_B`

Example :

```
import datatable as dt

dt_f_A = dt.Frame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":['a','b','c','d']})
dt_f_B = dt.Frame({"c":[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4], "d":['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']})

dt_f_A.cbind(dt_f_B)

#dt_f_A[:, dt_f_B.names] = dt_f_B # it's work fine also

print(dt_f_A)
```

**Case 2:** **The number of rows is different**

- `dt_f_A.cbind(dt_f_B)` gives InvalidOperationError: Cannot cbind frame with X rows to a frame with Y rows.   (X ≠ Y)
- `dt_f_A[:, dt_f_B.names]` gives ValueError: Frame has **X** rows, and cannot be used in an expression where **Y** are expected.   (X ≠ Y)

**The solution :** use `dt_f_A.cbind(dt_f_B,force=True)`

Example:

```
import datatable as dt

dt_f_A = dt.Frame({"a":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6], "b":['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f']})
dt_f_B = dt.Frame({"c":[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4], "d":['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']})

dt_f_A.cbind(dt_f_B,force=True)

print(dt_f_A)
```

The missing value, then will be filled with **NA**

**Case 3:** **the attributes are not unique** (there is a duplication)

- `dt_f_A.cbind(dt_f_B)` : It works and gives a warning. It changes the duplicated attribute to a unique attribute:  atatableWarning: Duplicate column name found, and was assigned a unique name: 'a' -> 'a.0'
- `dt_f_A[:, dt_f_B.names] = dt_f_B` : IT doesn't give any error. It eliminate the duplicated column in **dt_f_A** and keep the column in **dt_f_B**.

Example:

```
import datatable as dt

dt_f_A = dt.Frame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":['a','b','c','d']})
dt_f_B = dt.Frame({"a":[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4], "d":['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']})

dt_f_A.cbind(dt_f_B) # rename the duplicated columns
#dt_f_A[:, dt_f_B.names] = dt_f_B # keep only the duplicated columns in dt_f_B

print(dt_f_A)
```

@sammywemmy Thank you for your valuable comment :)

Comment: note that for this to work, they should have same number of rows, and unique values in the columns; the assumption here is that you are certain of the number of rows and the uniqueness of the values in each column (there are no repeats)

Comment: @sammywemmy , thank you very much for your valuable comment. I changed the question and the answer as well to cover the three cases. Also, I thanked you in the main answer and question. Thank you again.